# Filtering out bad characters using a regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to filter out the char `^` before searching something in a database.

What will my regular expression look like if I want to achieve that the query will ignore the sign `^`?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5, and C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that. You can simply do this:

```
myString = myString.Replace("^", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter only that character, a simple *String.Replace()* call would suffice.

Anyway, if you want to use a regular expression, you must escape the `^`, since it is a special character.

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "\^+", String.Empty);
```